# Play Framework 2.1.2 internationalization doesn't work with Finnish characters

Tags: java, scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.1

I added messages.en and messages.fi files to conf folder (deleted original messages file). Then I added En and Fi buttons together with a router call, which call following Action in my controller.

```
public static Result change(String langCode) {
    currentLanguage = langCode;
    changeLang(langCode);
    return GO_HOME;
}
```

I use following structure in scala view files: @Messages("color.explanation").
I tried also importing internationalization in scala view files with following: @Messages.get("color.explanation").

I added the environment variable, which is mentioned in [another stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529753/scala-play-2-0-compilation-error-io-error-while-decoding) and [another stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036). But this didn't help.

Translations work perfectly by clicking except Finnish special characters. I get "N�ytet��n" instead of "Näytetään". What can be the reason, do you know any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check encoding of `messages` files, i.e. Idea for some reason creates `messages.xy` files initially with `iso-8859-1` encoding - it is probably because ***Standard Java API is designed to use ISO 8859-1 encoding for the properties file*** ([IntelliJ docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html)).

To switch to `utf-8` in Idea you need first `Mark as Plain text`, switch the encoding and finally `Mark as properties` the file again.

Of course it's quite possible that you use other IDE/text editor, anyway file's encoding is first thing you need to check,I can ensure you that Play supports perfectly messages files even in Chinese if they are encoded properly.

Comment: Hi, I am encoding the view files and messages files in following with notepad++: UTF-8 (gives compilation errors), UTF-8 without BOM (no errors, but still getting weird chars), ANSI (same as UTF-8 without BOM)

Comment: Wrong encoding is almost certainly the problem. We also have a project with many different languages, including Finnish, and they all work fine.

IDEA does have a habit of switching the encoding as well as many other editors. So it is very important to ensure it is UTF-8.

The other thing is that once you have messed up encodings you might need some hacking to get them back again.

Comment: When checking with notepad++ I wasn't able to change the encodings, yesterday I googled about changing encodings and tried with another (PsPad) editor. Thanks for your answers biesior and jody.

Comment: TIP: notepad++ is cool, but there are much nicer IDE's for working with Play, ie. Intellij Idea, which has support for Play 2.x

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that immediately come to mind:

1. You've got your messages file setup incorrectly. What I suspect you have is:

   ```
   color.explanation=Näytetään
   ```

   While what you should have is

   ```
   color.explanation=N\u00E4ytet\u00E4\u00E4n
   ```

   Not sure how you're building this, but both Maven and Ant can automatically translate the first form into the second form. Java is a bit weird about this, and I'm not sure why, but this is what you have to do. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle) question for more on this topic.
2. You may not be setting your `Content-Type` header correctly. What I would expect is something like this:

   ```
   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
   ```

   You can use, e.g., Google Chrome's Developer Tools to see what exactly is being sent back. If you're not sending back the right `charset`, it might just be that your browser is unable to figure out how to display that character. I don't know much about the Play Framework, so if this *is* your issue, I don't know how to resolve it.

Hopefully this will provide some insight and at least eliminate a couple of possibilities.

Comment: I am trying to set the Content-type by: 'response().setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");', in my controller, but that doesn't help

Comment: This isn't valid for Play. In Play the message resource files are not normal Java properties, they must be in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Oh right - thanks for that. All the Java frameworks that I've used have, that I can recall, expected standard Java I18N properties files.